# My Samsung Galaxy tab 2 (7.0) can't see 5ghz networks

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

My Samsung Galaxy tab 2 (7.0) can't see 5ghz networks.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Is your wifi's channel set to one the Galaxy Tab cannot operate with (due to legal restrictions you cannot use some channels in some countries, depends on your device' settings, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Limitations ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spec sheet](http://www.samsung.com/us/system/consumer/product/gt/p3/11/gtp3113tsyxar/Galaxy_Tab_II_7.0_Spec_Sheets_v14_1_.pdf) lists compatibility as "Wireless Internet WiFi 802.11 b/g/n, WiFi Direct".    If it has a 5 Ghz radio, it *should* list **a**/b/g/n.

Despite this, there are plenty of discussions around the net about getting the Galaxy Tab to work on a 5 Ghz AP, so your problem may be something else.

Comment: ***Entirely incorrect.***.  The earliest WiFi **802.11** (now called '802.11a') is generally universal, and often ignored when stating capabilities.  However, both WiFi **802.11a** and **802.11n** can support 2.4GHz and 5GHz, but this is **not** available unless both the AP (access point) and client (your device) both support 5GHz.  The other advantage for the 5GHz spectrum is that it is not overcrowded and is (generally) unaffected by cordless phones and microwave ovens.

Comment: A support is not 'generally universal'.  A does not predate B, both having been released in Sept 1999.  A does not operate in 2.4Ghz.  The term Wi-Fi is a trademark of the Wi-Fi Alliance, formed in 1999 to promote 802.11b.  It did not apply to 802.11a until 2002.  5 Ghz support didn't start to become popular until the days of the 'pre-N' routers, which offered an early implementation of MIMO and sometimes dual band.  A device marked B or G operates on 2.4Ghz.  A device marked A operates on 5.0Ghz.  A device marked N is ambiguous.  It's odd for a dual band device not to support A and say so.

Answer (score 2):

***Possible answer (untest)***

[Galaxy Tab 2 - 5GHz WiFi Support?](http://www.galaxytabforums.net/forum/galaxy-tab-2-general-discussions/4433-galaxy-tab-2-5ghz-wifi-support.html)

> *Q. Can anyone please confirm? seems strange a new device does NOT support 5GHz?*
>
> *A. If it's the same as the Tab ver 1 it only works if the router is on a low channel in the 5400 MHz range... Use 36... the high channels
>   at 5700 MHz don't work.*

[ More authorative later, I only bought my **Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0)** yesterday. ]

---

**UPDATE**

Tested with router 5MHz set to **channel 36**.

*Still unable to connect.*

Comment: Link without summary is not considered helpful as when the link dies the answer might be useless.